# How do I make a contain method in Notion look for two conditions?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, formula, notion

I have a Date field in Notion. It's setup is like this: December 7, 2022.
I have made a formula that looks for the month and then adds up expenses from that month. this is the formula:

```
contains(format(prop("Date")), "December") ? prop("Expenses") : 0
```

The problem is that I also need it to search for the year, but ignore the day. Is that possible at all?
Kind of like this, but it's not working:

```
contains(format(prop("Date")), "December" and "2022") ? prop("Expenses") : 0
```